# What is the meaning of colon (:) operator after member function name in php

Tags: php, oop

I want to know the meaning of colon after method name i.e.

> public function getTitle():Data {

```
interface Data { 
     public function details(string $name);
}
class Company {
     private $title;

     public function getTitle():Data {
      return $this->title;
     }

     public function setTitle(Data $title)
     {
      $this->title=$title
     }

}

.....
.....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public function getTitle():Data {
     return $this->title;
}
```

"[Return type declaration](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration)" added since PHP 7.0 (This method should return an object having type "Data").

Like "[Argument type declaration](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration)", "Return type declaration" is optional.

to check the new features introduced in PHP 7.0

check this link
http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php

Comment: As aditional information, PHP will throw a `TypeError`, if the value that is returned [cannot be converted to the specified type](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e8a04f88f485659358759cca4ff322238ade493a), or if [strict typing](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.strict) is activated.